Vlookup function for criteria contained in a multiple selection drop down list
I am trying to create a way to use vlookup or something similar to select and calculate a total using a drop down box with the ability to select multiple criteria.
I am using the standard vlookup to find one critera
=VLOOKUP(B36,B$19:C$30,2,0)

By adding multiple vlookup together eg..
=VLOOKUP(B37,B$19:C$30,2,0)+VLOOKUP(B38,B$19:C$30,2,0)

I can combine two critera/cells together.
What I want to do is use multiple critera in a multiple selection drop down box to return one value.
Eg.
A...............B

Apples .....1

Pears ......-1

Oranges....1

Drop down displaying....

Apples

Apples

Pears

Oranges

Expected Answer for the above dropdown: 2
I don't know if anyone else at somepoint may find this helpful.
But this formula
=SPLIT(B2,", ",FALSE)
Splits out the dropdown box into multcomponents
So far it's the only way I can come up with to get the information from a multiple drop down box.
I'd still like to use now the split function combined with vlookup if possible to then be able to return a value as per my original post.















You could directly use the split data in VLOOKUP, search argument, if it's inside a ARRAYFORMULA:
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(B2,", ",FALSE),B$19:C$30,2,0))

To sum within array context, use SUMPRODUCT:
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(B2,", ",FALSE),B$19:C$30,2,0))


Thank you that works very well the sumproduct is spot on was what I was looking for, I'm only just learning excel/google sheets can you point me in the right direction.? I think I understand the concept of the the arrayformula but I'm unsure how sumproduct does the same thing. It works exactly to how I wanted I just am trying to understand the concept and the formula thanks Kelsey.

@KelseyRogers There's no exact documentation. It's  just a known quirk that SUMPRODUCT(...) works like ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(...)). You can just use the latter, if you want more clarity.

if this answer satisfies your question, consider accepting it by choosing the checkmark on the left of this post. See how to accept
